Wannier90 input file for QE output
I want to plot HSE band structure of g-C3N4 with Wannier90.
I have done the SCF calculation with Quantum_Espresso, but I don't know how to set the win and pw2wan inputs to reach a good band structure. The band structure is not compatible with the references. Please, send me a reliable inputs of win and pw2wan.

+1. Welcome to our community.

Dear Nike, Thanks
